# How to select and insert to another temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
   ID   LogDate       LogTime         Mode  

   1    2017-02-23  19:30:00.0000000    1   
   4    2017-02-24  08:00:00.0000000    0
```

i got the above result.

I need to get the output as below

```
   LogDate        InTime               OutTime

   2017-02-23     19:30:00.0000000    08:00:00.0000000
```

**Updated Question**
Actually below table is the original table.From this table I needed to  get the first and last records and display first logtime as InTime and second logtime as OutTime as output

```
   ID   LogDate     LogTime        InoutMode    
    1   2017-02-23  19:30:00.0000000    1   
    2   2017-02-23  23:00:00.0000000    0   
    3   2017-02-23  23:30:00.0000000    1   
    4   2017-02-24  08:00:00.0000000    0
```

Comment: What is common in these 2 rows? Any ID? What if there are more than 2 rows returned? How will you handle it them?

Comment: I selected first and last row records from 1 temp table and get the first table result @ Utsav

Comment: @winner_joiner need help

Comment: Also need the time difference as another column @Meysam Chegini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need primery key for this select
but

```
     SELECT LogDate,
     LogTime  AS InTime,
     (
         SELECT TOP 1 t1.LogTime
         FROM   yourTable AS t1
         WHERE  Mode = 0
     )        AS OutTime   FROM   yourTable  WHERE  Mode = 1
```

Comment: Also need the time difference as another column @Meysam Chegini

Answer (score 1):

Use this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c74ea/5

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT t.*,
          row_Number() over (
                             ORDER BY logdate,logtime) AS inc,
          row_Number() over (
                             ORDER BY logdate DESC,logtime DESC) AS dec
   FROM table1 t)
SELECT t1.logdate,
       t1.logtime AS intime,
       t2.logtime AS outtime
FROM
  (SELECT logdate,
          logtime,
          inc
   FROM cte
   WHERE inc=1) t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT logdate,
          logtime,dec
   FROM cte
   WHERE dec=1) t2 ON t1.inc=t2.dec
```

Comment: ,Your answer is correct and perfect output for all records.